# How to create an iPhone app with Instant messaging functionality between users

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mobile, instant-messaging

I was wondering how to create an app for iOS which includes IM through socket communication: what code I would need and more importantly, how to set up a server.

I am aware of keywords like 'XMPP/Jabber Bot' but most of the information I have come across is a mix between Desktop and Mobile applications, I would like to a create a mobile application.

The server needs to be able to push notifications, send only text between devices, and deal with logins/creating independent user accounts. I would like to make this server myself so I do not have to pay a monthly fee, I was looking to create a server using something like a Raspberry Pi. Of course I would need to create a database for user information, as far as I am aware I would need PHP and MySQL. I am also unsure whether the database is part of the server, and how I would go about giving the server high storage or bandwidth.

All information would be extremely helpful, thank you in advance.

Comment: See the discussion of push notifications in the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html). Also see [Ray Wenderlich's Apple Push Notification Service](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) tutorial.

Answer (score 7):

What you need is to implement [XMPP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP). [Jabber](http://www.jabber.org/) is a open source project which implemented this protocol. You need to run a [eJabber](http://www.ejabberd.im/) server on your machines and a XMPP compliant client on your client machines. a connection is kept open between 2 people who chat and messages are pushed to the server and from server to other client(s).

Check this [Building a Jabber Client for iOS: XMPP Setup](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-integration/). It has more than enough help to get you going...